# How to print symbols

Tags: python

I'm having a problem printing these symbols: `♠ ♡ ♣ ♢`.
My program is quite simple:

```
SUITS = '♠ ♡ ♣ ♢'.split()
CARDS = '2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A'.split()

print(SUITS)
```

But, I'm having this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/wdiog/PycharmProjects/Novo_Projeto/Cartas_Jogo.py", line 12, in 
> print(NAIPES)
> File "C:\Users\wdiog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 2: character maps to

How to solve this. I want to be able to print ♠ ♡ ♣ ♢.

Comment: My python is able to, in what environment do you run that code ?

Comment: You are printing to the console. In order to be able to do that, the character you are printing has to be supported by the encoding used by the console. In your case, the console seems to be using windows-1252 encoding, which does not support those characters. You should set up the console (the Windows console, or DOS window, or whatever it is called) to use utf-8.

Comment: I can run it in Python 3.8.1 shell and in Windows CMD.  You should change the encoding as zvone has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
print (ord ('♣'))
print (chr (9827))
```

The `ord ()` gives you the number to use in `chr ()` so then you can just use `chr (number)` in your code.

Comment: The first print works, but the second doesn't. And the error message is the same:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wdiog/PycharmProjects/Novo_Projeto/Cartas_Jogo.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(chr(9827))
  File "C:\Users\wdiog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2663' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use python library 'ftfy'

Eg.

print('âœ” No problems with text') => âœ” No problems with text

import ftfy
print(ftfy.fix_text('âœ” No problems with text'))  => ✔ No problems with text